# Separate keys for the "About" string in the Transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, localization, international-sites, transifex

On SOen **About** on the tag page:

> [image: "About tag" on the tag page]

and in the footer:

> [image: "About" company in the footer]

are the same.

But on SOru (and, probably, on other localized sites) **about** in the footer is **О компании** (like **about the company**), and on the tag's page **О метке** (like, **about the tag**).

But right now for both cases is used string `8f7f4c1ce7a4f933663d10543562b096` in transfiex.

Could you separate those keys (one for footer and one for tag page)?

Discussion on SOru: [На странице метки не сходятся термины](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8064/15479).

Comment: @Adam, any progress there?

Comment: I have a PR ready for this, just need to get it approved/deployed.

Comment: @AdamLear thanks, Adam)

Comment: @AdamLear Any of the other Transifex issues slated for fixing as well?

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Eventually, probably. Everything that has a status tag is in our backlog, but when we get to it till vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coming in just shy of a 2 year wait... :)

The change is now live in production. You should see two variants of the "About" string: `About$~tag$` and `About$~company$`.

Comment: I see the new string "About the company" (`c10e788d978e346282d5b1704698820b`). But there is no new string for "About the tag" =\

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Hmm, interesting. There should be different variants for the string "About", similar to [this one for "quote"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14207). This was my first time adding one of these "refers to" variants, so I'll have to check and see what I missed tomorrow.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik Something fell over in the export of our strings to Transifex. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I forced it just now, and the strings are up: `68f068707be9a4ba8abc8156c92052c1` and `2ecae8496b4e728831856d9590e857b6`.

Comment: Need one more for [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369294/339911)