# Every "about" to translate should have its own source string

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization

An old issue regarding the "About" section of the profile: [Separate keys for the "About" string in the Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316766/339911) is happening again.

This time, it's in the new [user profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=profile) layout:

> [image: About (tag)]

For those unfamiliar, single words with multiple connotations or usages in English sometimes translate into multiple distinct words or phrases in other languages.

In this case, the string "About" on the user profile page currently uses the same translated string as the "About" used at the top of [tag wiki pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info). Since the translation of these two usages are distinct in Russian, **they need to have separate translation entries**: one for the tag case, and a new one for the user profile case.

Currently there are 3 source strings available:

- [About (Tag)](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15070)

  - Used on tag wiki pages
- [About (Company)](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15069)

  - Used in the site footer under "Company"
- [About (Default?)](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/5573)

  - Possibly the original "About" from before the separation of the term into multiple strings
  - This could potentially be used for the profile page, but it’s a poor solution in my view

---

While this is the only instance of this bug currently, it's important to note that *all* usages of "About" across the site need their own translation entries, paired with their own respective context information, to prevent this from occurring again and again in the future.

Comment: Making the English labels unambiguous might also be a good way forward; fix the root cause rather than the symptom.

Comment: @tripleee in general it's not possible to make labels unambiguous, since many times words are located in some context on the page, and using more words (unambiguous) instead one will clog the page and sometime broke design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue! I have added a translation to handle the special ["About (user)"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18843) case. It should now be correctly translated.

I made a pass through code to look for other "about" strings that may not be handled correctly -- there are a couple of others ("About Us", "About me") that are already being translated and I did not see any others, so this issue should now be addressed. That being said, the code base is quite large so please reach out if further instances are found.