# Add context "refers to site" for "About" used on welcome block for new users

Tags: bug, new-users, localization

If you are a new user to the site, you will see the welcome block on the right side of the main page:

> [image]

That block has three links in the bottom part:

- About
- Help
- Meta

Sometime ago, we decided that every "About" should have its context: [Every "about" to translate should have its own source string](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369294/339911). And nowadays [we have 3](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=About%24):

- tag
- company
- user

In the current case, it seems that wrong (or empty) context is used for the "About" link (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour?mnu=1).

Could we please add the new context here refers to site/tour:

> [image]